# PHP Array Implode eliminate the last glue on empty array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this 3 optional input text which is not required at all but at least one should be filled.

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="text2" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="text3" class="form-control">
```

and I put their values in array like this

```
$p =array{
    $this->input->post('text1'),
    $this->input->post('text2'),
    $this->input->post('text3')
}
```

If I only filled 2 fields, the result is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Jack
    [2] => 
)
```

I implode them:

```
$passenger = implode(',', $p);
```

The result:

```
John, Jack,
```

What I want is:

```
John, Jack
```

How to eliminate the last `','` using PHP? Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_filter` to remove the empty entries from your array before imploding it.

```
$passenger = implode(',', array_filter($p));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be use trim function.

```
$passenger = trim(implode(',', $p),",");
```

or

```
$passenger = implode(',', $p);
$passenger = trim($passenger,",");
```

Also In Case of This Array

```
Array
(
    [1] => Jack
    [2] => 
    [3] => ,
)
```

Trim Work Perfectly.

```
$passenger = trim(implode(',', $p),",");
```

Output: 
Jack